# Unable to connect to local domain from laptop

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, windows-server-2012

I have a laptop that was recently factory restored and given to another user in our office. Previously, it connected to the local network fine, and was able to ping our local office server (which is our AD server, and our local DNS server (windows 2012 R2)), via IP address and domain (CENTURION). After factory restore, the laptop can no longer ping via domain, nor can join the local AD domain, because it says the domain can't be found.

Could somebody please offer me some assistance in fixing this?

I have tried both wirelessly and wired, and have also issued the following commands:

```
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /flushdns
```

I have even set DHCP to automatic, and manually set the IP, and the primary dns server is set to my local dns server's IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this. Newer versions of Windows do not allow single-label domain names (like EXAMPLE). Our local domain is 'CENTURION'.

There was a regedit flag I had to enable in order to allow connecting to this.

From what I read online, this applies to Anything above Windows 7.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters] and add a new DWORD: AllowSingleLabelDnsDomain with a value of 1.

Upon restarting, you can connect to single label domains.